# detect react native android app crash using webdriver-io

Tags: selenium-grid, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm pretty new at my work using appium, webdriverio and selenium grid. Trying to improve error handling and logging on our test framework.

Is there a way of checking if the app has crashed within the test case flow using the tools mentioned above?

I found some indications to using event listeners in combination with `try-catch` blocks and `assert`, but no example of how this can be implemented. (Have no idea of how event listeners on mobile would work).

N.B.: there is no android pop-up message about the app closing unexpectedly.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.